# Mostrar y ocultar un div con media query

Tags: css

He intentado sin éxito mostrar y ocultar una clase llamada "min_footer". Quiero que esa clase se oculte si el ancho del navegador es superior a 880 y si el ancho es igual o menor a 880 la clase debe mostrar su contenido.

El código es el siguiente:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 880px) {
.min_footer {
 display: none !important;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 880px) {
 .min_footer {
  display: block !important;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="min_footer">
    <?php include ("min_footer.php"); ?>
  </div>
```

Tengo otro media query que trabaja sin problemas con un código casi idéntico, así que descarté que el problema sea debido a uso del "include" de PHP.

La web en cuestión es esta: [ishameetings.cl](http://ishameetings.cl/) y la clase "min_footer" está en el pie de esa página web. Por otro lado al disminuir el ancho se puede comprobar que el contenido no quiere mostrarse.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier sugerencia es agradecida.

Comment: lo probe asi como lo tienes y si me funciona, tu include esta bien direccionado? es decir la ruta es correcta?

Comment: en que entorno estas probando?

Comment: La ruta, está correcta, así como además el nombre del archivo. Estoy utilizando WordPress. Yo creo que es un conflicto de estilos, porque utilizo un plugin para agregarlos sin editar directamente el tema, porque para mí de está forma es más ordenado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo único que veo de extraño es que **redundas** al poner la media query `max-width: 880px` ya que, cuando el ancho del viewport sea menor a `880px`, se dejarán de aplicar el `display: none` que definiste en la media query.

**Ejemplo**

```css
.min_footer {
  background-color: coral;
  height: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 880px) {
  .min_footer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="min_footer">

</div>
```

---

Click en "página completa" para ver el funcionamiento de la media query.

Comment: Lo he intentado modificando el código, cambiando las extensiones del min_footer.php a min_footer.php. Incluso saqué el "include" y coloqué un "hola mundo" y tampoco funciona. Aún no lo comprendo, el primer include funciona sin problemas y el segundo no.

Comment: ¿Funciona en el ejemplo? Sí. Eso quiere decir **que las media queries están bien**, por lo que el problema parece estar en otro lado o hay un conflicto de estilos. ¿Tienes una URL a la mano para echarle un ojo?

Comment: Claro, está es la web: http://ishameetings.cl

Comment: Curioso, la clase `.min-footer` en el inspector no tiene ninguna regla CSS. Las reglas las hereda del padre.

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería funcionarte

si es MENOR a 880, mostrara el contenido

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 880px) {
 .min_footer {
    display: block !important;
 }
}
```

si es MAYOR oculta el contenido

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) and (min-width: 881px) {
 .min_footer {
     display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Lo he incluido y aún no funciona. Es muy raro el primer include si funciona y el segundo no. Incluso descarté hasta los detalles más tantos como el nombre y tipo de archivo que importo además de comprobar que las clase de CSS este bien escrita.

Answer (score 0):

Por fin he podido arreglarlo utilizando como base sus códigos y un poco de imaginación. Al final tuve que esconder todas las clases "hijo" dentro de la clase min_footer. No sé porque ocurre ese problema, quizás es incompatibilidad de plugins en WordPress. De todas formas dejo los estilos para que alguien le sea útil.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 880px) {
 .min_footer {
  display: none;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 880px) {
 .columnas_pie {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .creditos {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .mailchimp_twitter {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .logo_certificacion {
  display: none;
 }
}
```